# I need length of text in sql position()

Tags: sql, position

I need a formula to know the length through position(). in "vinod2802@gmail.com54523" where ".com" comes in position().

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  But in general databases provide a function such as `instr()`, `position()`, or `charindex()` for this purpose.

Comment: position() would be helpful

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the specific implementation of SQL that you are using, since the correct answer will vary depending on that, and the idea of StackOverflow is that your question can be useful to others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query that will return the length of the desired string.

```
Select CHARINDEX('.',reverse('vinod2802@gmail.com54523'))-1
```

SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `.com` start position ,so mainly you need `.` position

in SQL server

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('.', 'vinod2802@gmail.com54523') AS MatchPosition;
```

Mysql & postgreSQL

```
SELECT POSITION('com' IN 'vinod2802@gmail.com54523');
```